# Replace Parent Theme Thumbnail image on WordPress Update Page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-theme-astra

I use Astra and Astra Pro for my client websites. The Astra Theme is the parent theme and each client then becomes a child theme. In Astra Pro I set the White Label so the customer should only see my agency's information. That all works as expected.

The problem lies when the parent Astra Theme needs an update. When you open the WordPress Update page and look under Themes, the theme name is set correctly per the White Label function, but the thumbnail is for the Astra Theme.

I've spent the last hour searching for how to replace this image but to no avail.

I am sure there is a hook somewhere where I can do this, but I've failed to find it. Does anyone know how to change this?

I am sure this affects not only Astra users, but users of other theme templates as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't help but as a temporary solution you could swap it with javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought of that. If I can just figure out the hook for when the template list is created I can take it from there. Appreciate it!